# How to get Sum of Special fields?

Tags: report, stimulsoft

I have a report with a table, and the table have multy fields.(Id,Name,Peyment,Type)

I want get sum of Peyment where Type is "1".

How to get sum of value whit special type?

I use

```
{SumI(Table.Payment,Table.Id='1')}
```

and this

```
{IIF(Table.Type=='1',SumI(Table.Payment),0)}
```

but i get error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a compare operator in the Sum statement (e.g. ==) and double quotes.

E.g.

```
{SumIfRunning(Table.Payment,Table.Type=="1")}
```